# Pine script syntax error when modifying variable

Tags: pine-script, trading, metatrader4, tradingview-api

I have a script that has two separate functions

1. check for a condition and if met, set variable of that index to true
2. Loop through the past variable and modify a value if a different condition is met

I have an issue inside the second function, where I cannot modify the variable and I get a syntax error

```
isREY() =>

    bullREY = false
    bearREY = false
    bullREY_index = 0
    bearREY_index = 0

    bullishREY = (close > high[2])
    bearishREY = (close < low[2])

    if bullishREY
        bullREY := true
        bullREY_index := bar_index

    if bearishREY
        bearREY := true
        bearREY_index := bar_index   

    [bullREY, bearREY, bullREY_index, bearREY_index]
[bullREY, bearREY, bullREY_index, bearREY_index] = isREY()

filledREY(num) =>
    for i = 0 to num
        if bearREY[i] and high > low[i+2]
            label.new(bar_index, high, "Filled " + tostring(bearREY_index[i]))
            bearREY[i] = false   // ERROR HERE
            bearREY_index[i] := 0   // ERROR HERE

filledREY(10)
```

How do I achieve the solution Im trying here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post your entire script? Makes it easier to investigate. I assume that the error associated with the reference to the bars in the future `low[i+2]`.

Comment: I cannot provide the entire script, the only thing different is the bullish/bearishREY formula. low[i+2] is 2 bars behind, not in the future. The issue here is not the logic but the syntax error.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `low[i+2]` is 2 bars behind. The syntax error occurs because you are trying to change the value on a historical bar `[i]`.

Comment: Perhaps this can be done through `array`.

Comment: Correct. You can't change past values in a series like you did here: `bearREY[i] = false`.  Note that in pine `[]` is a history reference operator, but not the array's index (as the variables are series objects, not array). AnyDozer is right, you can rewrite the code with array of series instead of series variables and then you can manipulate, sort re-arrange etc the content of array.

Comment: Thank you guys! Yes, arrays was the right way to go about this.